# Make zoom with Kinect camera

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv, kinect-sdk

I'm using kinect camera for a new application, with Microsoft.Kinect sdk and EmguCV.

Is there any way to make zoom with the camera?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no optical zoom in the Microsoft Kinect hardware.  You can either:

1. Attach a 3rd party add-on, such as the [Nyko Zoom](http://www.nyko.com/products/product-detail/?name=Zoom)
2. Code a digital zoom into your application